# How to fix this Django mysql databse Heroku Error?

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

database =  cleardb (mysql)
I tried doing a syncdb and this is what it always gives me:

```
 File "/app/gettingstarted/settings.py", line 85, in <module>
 DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
 TypeError: 'set' object does not support item assignment
```

I followed the getting started tutorial to the t.

There is no code in my models.py file, also this error is appearing in terminal

My settings.py database config looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {'default'}

DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are initializing your `DATABASE` dict in the wrong way, It shoud be

```
DATABASES = {}

DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, is there a tutorial somewhere or something that specified this?

Comment: @user3806832 you dont need a tut, just you cant use a python dictorionary without initialize it.